# Polymer 1.4 dom-bind defining properrties

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

In the index.html I use:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
```

In a normal dom-module I use:

```
 <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-xxxx',
       properties: {
       /* location for properties */
       }
```

Where do I define the properties used in the template dom-bind (f.i to have an observer attached to them?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind), you'd use JavaScript (inline or imported in `index.html`) to add template properties inside of an event handler for the template's `dom-change` event. For example, you could add a `message` property to the template with this script:

```
var t = document.getElementById('app');
t.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
  t.message = 'Hello world!';
});
```

See demo below:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    {{message}}
  </template>

  <script>
    var t = document.getElementById('app');

    // The dom-change event signifies when the template has stamped its DOM.
    t.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
      // auto-binding template is ready.
      t.message = 'Hello world!';
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/biharo/edit?html,output)</sup>

Comment: This works for adding an initial value to a property. But how do I define other elements which are normally declared inside polymer properies like type (Number, String etc) annotations like readOnly and most if all observer

Comment: There's no Polymer API to observe properties (or create property objects) from an auto-binding template. Why wouldn't you just use a Polymer element instead?

Comment: that is what I would do, but the Polymer starter kit (PSK) application does not do that and we have to learn our student to work according to what is advised (what is in the PSK).

Comment: PSK does actually have [custom elements](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/tree/master/app/elements).

Comment: but all custum elements have to be activated in the data-route sections which are activated in menu's all inside the index.html. This requires  quite a lot of data binding to properties inside the index.html. Because there is data-binding one could try to use computed properties to bind to and/or observers which modify fields to bind to. I would expect that somewhere I could define the polymer properties but when  using template dom-bind with id="app"' I cannot use polymer is="app"  neither I can change the template dombind having id="my-app" and having polymer is="my-app".

Comment: Custom elements do not need to be in data-route sections. They can exist just about anywhere in the body. In fact, you can encapsulate an entire app inside a custom element, where index.html contained only a single tag.

Comment: Sorry of you misunderstood My comment. Psk is setup with data route sections. When you want to use these section you fill them with your applications custom elements. These elements communicate which each other using databinding. Databinding involves properties, computer properties and observers

    **problem: where to define these observers.**

Ofcourse one can ignore psk. Define polymair element in index.html and in that mimic the index.html of psk. But I expect the authors of pk have thought of the Observer problem and have a solution else they would have setup psk in another way.